# Displaying errors with sweave

Tags: r, latex, stderr, sweave

I'm writing some R notes with Sweave and would like to show common errors. For example,

```
<<echo=TRUE, eval=TRUE>>=
x = 5
#Case matters!
x*X
@
```

However when sweaving, the document won't compile due to the R error. Is there any way to make sweave compile and show the (nicely formated) error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Shane suggests, use

```
<<echo=TRUE,eval=FALSE>>
```

for the code that will error, but you want to display, and then again with

```
<<echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE,results=verbatim>>
```

but with the same code wrapped in a try.

There's an example here: 
http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/09/11690.html

Answer (score 8):

This is a non-issue with [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/), the "next generation `Sweave`", if I may say so. It displays errors and warnings by default, which was difficult or impossible in `Sweave`, along with a plethora of other nice features (like syntax coloring, PGF integration and plot animation, for starters). It is developed and maintained actively, too.

`Sweave` code must be converted once using the function `Sweave2knitr` provided by the same package.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your error in a `try()` command.  Then it will keep running:

```
> {print(1); try(x*X); print(2)}
[1] 1
Error in try(x * X) : object 'X' not found
[1] 2
```

Comment: I thought of that, but would like to avoid displaying 'try'

Comment: My other thought was that there might be an options(error=some.function) that could work, but I can't find anything.  You could call each piece of code twice: once with a try and echo=FALSE but eval=TRUE and capture the error message.  Then once without the try and the settings reversed.  Then just print out the error message separately.