# How to include R stderr output in Sweave document

Tags: r, stderr, sweave

I'm working on R package vignettes and there are a number of cases where I'd like to include the error output in the document as an example for users.

So the Sweave code chunk

```
<<throws_error>>=
 stop('hello')
@
```

would ideally produce a document with

```
stop('hello')
Error: hello
```

My real example is a fairly long running process, and I'd like to capture output of warnings and messages as well as errors.

I've messed around with various Sweave code chunk include params. Only solution I've come up with is to have a hidden code chunk that prints the error text with `cat()` --which kind of defeats the purpose of using Sweave.  Seems like there might be a solution possible with the `sink()` function to somehow redirect stderr, but haven't been able to figure that out either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How about a verbatim latex environment?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3131270/946850

Comment: added clarification to my question that it is a long running process (so I'd rather not run it twice as that main answer suggests) and I'd also like to capture warning output, which I don't think 'cat()' will grab.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use `Sweave` or `knitr` to generate your LaTeX and pdf files ?

By default with `knitr` under RStudio, the produced document is almost exactly what you want to get.

Under Sweave, you can use the following workaround, taken from [this message on R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-August/286298.html) :

```
%outputs the R code but does not execute it. So no error
<<echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE>>=
 stop('hello')
@

% executes the code but displays only the error
<<echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE>>=
cat(try(stop('hello')))
@
```

Comment: I've used Sweave, I'll try with knitr. If I go that route, is there a way to let `R CMD build` or CRAN's build process know to use kniter instead of Sweave when rebuilding package vignettes?

Comment: @skyebend It should be possible with R 3.0.0 without a workaround. See here : http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/vignette/

Comment: Knitr works great! But I'm stuck in R 2.* for now,so my .Rnw file fails `R CMD check`. :-( Hopefully can move to R 3 in a couple months.  Also the hidden `cat(try())` solution doesn't work for me as it includes the call in the output:

    % executes the code but displays only the error
    <<echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE>>=
    cat(try(stop('hello')))
    @

    Error in try(stop("hello")) : hello

And it shows the `warning()` text, but not `message()` text.